# Upper Triangular Implies Diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

If all matrices can be made upper - triangular with respect to some basis by:

> Suppose V is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and T is a linear transformation.
>   Then T has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of V.

And any upper - triangular matrix can be made orthogonal:

> Suppose T is a linear transformation. If T has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some
>   basis of V, then T has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some
>   orthonormal basis of V.

But it's clear that an upper-triangular and orthonormal matrix must be a diagonal matrix. This implies every matrix has a diagonal matrix which we know to false as it was stated earlier to not be true. What am I missing?

Comment: The second statement says that the *basis* is orthonormal, but the matrix remains upper-triangular only.

Comment: You've hit on a point I had some confusion over. Won't T be diagonal for this basis by https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/show-that-an-orthogonal-matrix-that-is-upper-triangular-must-be-diagonal/ ?

Comment: The assertion is that there exist an orthogonal matrix $M$ and an upper-triangular matrix $U$ such that $T = MUM^T$. Note that $U$ is not (in general) orthogonal or diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix like $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ cannot be made diagonal for any base in $\mathbb{R}^2$

For more info on why this is the case, check:

- [Eigenvalues and eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)
- [Diagonalizable matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix)
- [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)

Long story short, a matrix is not diagonalizable if there is an eigenvalue whose algebraic and geometric multiplicity do not equal each other (in the example, the eigenvector $1$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ but geometric mulitplicity $1$)